# Content Decoding error with Babaganoosh

Tags: babaganoush-sitefinity

I'm getting this error on a fresh Sitefinity instance (7.0) when trying to load News, or Blogposts etc.

~/api/news
~/api/blogposts

```
Content Encoding Error
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This actually may be a bug with Web Essentials plugin for Visual Studio. Try disabling `Browser Link`:

[image]

If this doesn't work, try disabling `dynamicCompressionBeforeCache` in the web.config.

Comment: It was due to the use of the RadCompression module from Telerik. If I disable this module, the error is gone. Leaves me with another message:

No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/valueinvesting/api/news'.No type was found that matches the controller named 'news'.

Comment: OK, I see the problem. It uses Sitefinity 7.0.5100 and my site is on 7.0.5112. Bummer! Update available?

Comment: Update released but only against the latest official 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, just put some assembly bindings in your config.